# Swift Parse: How to fetch data from parse in a custom array?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, parse-platform

i want to fetch all data from parse with two where clauses (`where sender == "String" AND where receiver == "String"`) ordered by `"createdAt" DESC` (the latest entry should be the last one in the array) .

Then I want the result in this form:

```
var messages = 
[0: ["sender": "user1", "receiver": "user2", "time": "timestamp", "message": "footer"],
1: ["sender": "user1", "receiver": "user2", "time": "timestamp", "message": "footer"],
2: ["sender": "user1", "receiver": "user2", "time": "timestamp", "message": "footer"]]
```

I want to use this array outside the completion handler of e.g. fetchObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock()

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to take a look at [Parse queries guide](https://www.parse.com/docs/ios/guide#queries).

```
var found: [AnyObject]?
let q = PFQuery(className: "classname")
q.whereKey("sender", equalTo: "String")
q.whereKey("receiver", equalTo: "String")
q.addAscendingOrder("createdAt")
q.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (result, error) -> Void in
    found = result
}
```

Comment: I did this but the code there, and your code as well, is not the answer to my question.

Comment: After `found=result` I can't use `found` because the fetching executes in background

Comment: @PhilHarmonie it's strange that you didn't post this code in your question than. You can use `found` after query fetches the objects.

Comment: You can use `found` if you access it after search completes. You can determine when it completes in a number of ways. How about adding an observer and posting a notification when search completes?

Comment: Could yo post an expamle for that?